# JSON Parsing & Optionals in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

So i recently updated to Swift 3/XCode 8 and some of my code went hay-wire. I've read that some syntax changes have been made but I can't seem get this one right.
I make a request to Twitter and get JSON back:

```
func forLoadStats(completion: (AnyObject?, NSError?) -> Void)
{
    var clientError: NSError?
    let idString = api.getUserID()
    let client = TWTRAPIClient()
    let request = client.urlRequest(withMethod: "GET", url: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json", parameters: ["user_id" : 27446437], error: &clientError)
    client.sendTwitterRequest(request)
   { (response, data, connectionError) in

    if (connectionError == nil)
    {
    do {
        if let json: Any = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [AnyObject]
            {
            if let json = json, let immage = json?["profile_image_url_https"] as? String
                {
                //Make ProfilePic edges round
                self.profPic.layer.cornerRadius = 42
                self.profPic.clipsToBounds = true

                //let immage = image["profile_image_url_https"] as String
                let _vImageUrl = immage.replacingOccurrences(of: "_normal", with: "")
                let urlProfilePic = NSURL(string: _vImageUrl)
                let  urlPP = NSData(contentsOf: urlProfilePic! as URL)
                self.profPic.image = UIImage(data: urlPP! as Data)

                let ScrName = json["screen_name"] as! String
                self.scrNameLabel.text = "@\(ScrName)"

                //Populate Followers Label.text
                let flwrVar = json["followers_count"] as! Int
                self.followerLbl.text = "\(flwrVar)"

                //Populate Following Label.text
                let flwngVar = json["friends_count"] as! Int
                self.followingLbl.text = "\(flwngVar)"

                //Populate Bio
                let bio = json["description"] as! String
                self.bioLabel.text = "\(bio)"

                //created at date
                let accountAge = json["created_at"] as! String

                self.createdLbl.text = "\(accountAge)"

                let tweetCount = json["statuses_count"] as! Int
                self.tweetCount.text = "\(tweetCount)"

                let likes = json["favourites_count"] as! Int
                self.likesCount.text = "\(likes)"

                let lists = json["listed_count"] as! Int
                self.listedCount.text = "\(lists)"
                }
            }
        }
        catch let error
        {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
}
```

I get an error on the second "If let" statement that says: "initializer for conditional binding must have optional type not 'Any.
Can someone explain why this is?

Comment: seems as though the error is stemming from this line `if let json: Any = try?`... Also the second `if let` line here `let json = json, let immage = json?` seems to me like it's an invalid `IF` comparison so try looking at those

Comment: @KSigWyatt But what exactly could it be. Can't think of anything at the moment.

Comment: What's the purpose to annotate `Any` and cast to `[AnyObject]`  which is actually `[String:Any]` ???

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is obviously a dictionary, a JSON dictionary in Swift 3 is `[String:Any]`

You caused the error by the silly `Any` annotation (which is supposed to be `Any?` but is practically nonsensical) because it confuses the compiler.

If you use a `do` block, `try` without question mark but use optional binding:

```
...
if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any] {
   if let immage = json["profile_image_url_https"] as? String { ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It compiled. Still getting used to Swift syntax so I still have many rivers to cross, me thinks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with the syntax.  [AnyObject] will not work to use reference items such as json["profile_image_url_https"].  also, you are redeclaring json through let json = json, which makes it a non option in your let immage = json?["profile_image_url_https"] call, so that becomes a problem.  This structure does not have any compiler errors

```
if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any]
{
    if let json = json, let immage = json["profile_image_url_https"] as? String
    {
    }
}
```

This does not have any compiler errors.